# Is it possible to access data member of capture object?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl

Since C++14 it is possible to capture with intialization in a lambda expression. Often, this explained by saying that the lambda expression

```cpp
auto capture_obj1 = [A = B] (...) {...};
```

defines and instantiates an unnamed `struct` in the following way:

```cpp
auto capture_obj2 = struct LAMBDA {
  auto operator() (...) const {...}

  auto A = B;
} ();
```

Is it possible to somehow access the "data member" of `capture_obj1` as one would with `capture_obj2.A`?

As an example, consider the `Sum`-example from [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). One could replace

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Sum
{
    Sum(): sum{0} { }
    void operator()(int n) { sum += n; }
    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 8, 15, 267};
    Sum s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), Sum());
    std::cout << "sum: " << s.sum << '\n';
}
```

by

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums{3, 4, 2, 8, 15, 267};
    auto s = std::for_each(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [sum=0] (int n) mutable { sum += n; });
    std::cout << "sum: " << s.sum << '\n';
}
```

except that one cannot access `s.sum` in this way. See also [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m9PnRR).

Comment: @NutCracker As you can see on its cppreference site, it has.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: No.

Comment: If you need outside access, declare a variable and capture by reference.

Comment: For this specific problem, you should use [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead.

Comment: Hack: `[sum = 0] (int n = 0) mutable { return sum += n; })` and then `... << s()`.